# Rails factory girl how can I create a factory for this set of associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a Day model, and a day model can have many time_slots.

The day model looks as follows:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: days
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  schedule_id :integer
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#  wday        :integer
#

class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule
  has_many :time_slots, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

The TimeSlot model looks as follows:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: time_slots
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  day_id       :integer
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#  pin          :string
#  start_hour   :integer
#  start_minute :integer
#  end_hour     :integer
#  end_minute   :integer
#

class TimeSlot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :day
  has_many :passes, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :start_hour, :presence => true

  validates :start_minute, :presence => true

  validates :end_hour, :presence => true

  validates :end_minute, :presence => true
end
```

I currently have the following factory for day:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: days
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  schedule_id :integer
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#  wday        :integer
#

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :day do
    wday rand(0..6)

  after(:create) do |day, evaluator|
        create_list(:time_slots, 2, day: day,start_hour: generate :start_hour, start_min: generate :start_min, end_hour: generate :end_hour,end_min: generate :end_min)
  end

  end

  sequence :start_hour do |n|
    #Needs to return something between 00 and 23
    n
  end

  sequence :start_min do |n|
    #Needs to return something between 00 and 55
    n
  end

  sequence :end_hour do |n|
    #Needs to return something between 00 and 23 but a value HIGHER than start_hour
    #If end_min == start_min
    n
  end

  sequence :end_min do |n|
    #Needs to return something between 00 and 55 but a value that is definitely after start_min if end_hour and start_hour are equal 
    n
  end



end
```

Basically - My day has to have time_slots which make sense i.e a day could have the following which would be valid:

```
Timeslot 1
start_hour : 10
start_min : 00
end_hour : 11
end_min : 00

Timeslot 2
start_hour : 11
start_min : 00
end_hour : 12
end_min : 00
```

However this would not be valid as timeslot 2 overlaps with timeslot 1. Equally 2 identical time_slots are not valid:

```
Timeslot 1
start_hour : 10
start_min : 00
end_hour : 11
end_min : 00

Timeslot 2
start_hour : 10
start_min : 30
end_hour : 11
end_min : 00
```

It seems sequences may be able to help me here...this would be easy if I had a 'global' set of start mins, start hours etc as I could just pick the next one off the array but I don't know if that is possible or if there is a better way?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think I'd not use factory_girl for that. Instead I'd **visibly** create my timeslots in the tests.

But, you could go with this:

```
sequence :start_hour do |n|
  #Needs to return something between 00 and 23
  raise 'No more timeslots available' if n == 24
  n - 1 # if factory_girl starts with 1
end

sequence :start_min do |n|
  #Needs to return something between 00 and 55
  0 # Just always zero
end

sequence :end_hour do |n|
  #Needs to return something between 00 and 23 but a value HIGHER than    start_hour
  #If end_min == start_min
  n - 1
end

sequence :end_min do |n|
  #Needs to return something between 00 and 55 but a value that is definitely after start_min if end_hour and start_hour are equal 
  55 # like always 55 minute slots
end
```

So basically, you can play around with the `n`.

I hope factory_girl is consistent with the `n`s. Otherwise, you could try a bigger loop using the `n`.

Comment: so what is n...a number? Doesnt it increment? Does n-1 not reduce n by 1...meaning start_hour and end_hour could still be the same? Is n global across all sequences so guaranteed to be unique across all the sequence generators?

Comment: `n` increments with every call to factory_girl like "create".

Comment: Well, granted, I haven't tested it, but it were strange, if not. Actually, I just copied from your question.

Comment: But in that case we would end up with n = 0 so -1 for start hour,  0 for start_min , -1 for end hour 55 for end min....

Comment: Ok, sorry ... I just saw. You put those sequence blocks **within** your `day` factory. They should start with '1'.

Comment: Ok so they were already in the day factory...so what would the values be for the start hour end hour start min end min on the first set of calls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110424/discussion-between-andreas-gnyp-and-renegadeandy).